# The vector field is perpendicular to the family of level surfaces

Tags: calculus

The vector field given by $F(x,y,z)=\left\langle-x,-y,-z \right\rangle $ is perpendicular to the family of level surfaces is composed of

$(1)$ spheres

$(2)$ ellipsoid,

$(3)$ planes,

$(4)$ None of the above.

**Answer:**

The option $(3)$ is true.

Am I right?

Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is:

> The gradient of $f = f(x, y, z)$ is perpendicular to the level curves of $f$.

In your case you know the gradient ${\bf F}(x, y, z) = -(x, y, z) = -{\bf r}$, where ${\bf r}$ is the radial vector. So the question becomes: what is the surface to which the radial vector is perpendicular everywhere? And the solution is *a sphere*. In other words, the function level curves of $f$ are spheres centered at the origin.

Note that in you post you calculate the divergence of ${\bf}$: ${\bf \nabla} \cdot {\bf F} = -3$, but that doesn't have any particular meaning in this problem.